# Bootstrap4 navbar menu don´t work when I change browser size

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 navbar from CDN, and the navbar menu don't show the options when I change the browser resolution, I can´t see where the error is, any suggerence is wellcome. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap ejemplo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Content here -->

    <!-- Navar from bootstrap examples -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">::Places2Go::</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>



        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the correct target for the collapse. It should be `data-target="#navbarNav"` since `id=navbarNav` in the `navbar-collapse`.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/UgE34pBrMn

Comment: Thanks! It was ok, and I also needed to add jquery

Answer (score 1):

you need to add jQuery to your file https://jquery.com/

Comment: Yes, the solution was add jQuery and also change data-target="#navbarNav" since id=navbarNav in the navbar-collapse, it was said by @ZimSystem